# Can the variables for a regression be replaced?

Tags: regression

Does it play a role which of both variables X, Y is determined on the other one?

I think in case of a straight linear curve it should provide the same results(?) but what about a quadratic curve: y(x) = x² ?

Will y(x=?)=10=x² be the same like y=x² with x=3,162..?

Comment: In your question, what parameter is to be found by regression?

Comment: in principle both, the one in the one case and the other in the other case. When y=10 is demanded, then x has to be estimated and when x=3,162 is given, then y is sought.